# Browser freezing after selecting file in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form containing an input file field [`<input type="file" id="select-file" accept=".md"><label for="select-file">Select import file</label>`]. It has defined a jQuery handler for the change event [`$("#form").on("change", "#select-file", handler)`] to fire as soon as I selected a file.

It works flawlessly on Linux with Firefox at **work** and at **home** with Windows using Firefox and Chrome.

Instead at **work** with Windows using Chrome or Firefox, the browser freeze for about 8 sec after selecting the file. Only after this hiatus I can push other buttons on the form and the "change" event fires.

Discarding the hypothesis that Windows and work does not mesh, the freeze seems related to the different network disks available at work. Can anyone suggest what I have to check and hopefully a way to avoid the freeze? Thanks!

Small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>File Select</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="import-form">
    <input type="file" id="select-file" accept=".md">
    <label for="select-file">Select a file</label>
    <p id="selected-file">No file selected</p>
</div>
<script>
$("#import-form").on("change", "#select-file", function(e) {
    $("#selected-file").text(e.target.value.split('\\').pop());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `.size` of the selected `File` ?

Comment: No style at all. It happens even with a barebone element (I'll add a short example to my question)

Comment: Was not referencing `style` attribute, but the `File.size` of selected `.files[0]` object. That is, what is the file size of the selected file?

Comment: The file it is only 878 bytes

Comment: I'm testing cycling between 4 markdown files with size 878 - 47145 bytes

Comment: What do you mean by "cycling between"? The browser is retrieving file from memory if file is 47145 bytes. What is `RAM` of computer used?

Comment: To avoid the problem of not loading the same file twice, I use in turn one of the four files. Nothing special. The same machine, same used RAM is at work and at home, so don't think it is a problem of resource exhaustion. Anyway, I'll redo the test after a reboot here and at home.

Comment: Still nowadays I am haunted by this problem. Sometimes the change callback is hit immediately after choosing the file. Other times it takes up to 5 seconds. If I click anywhere on the browser's window, I hear the windows chime. Facebook file uploader works perfectly, though...

Comment: Could not describe this bug better than @StinkyCat. Same in Chrome 66 and Firefox 60. Surprisingly enough, no problem with Internet Explorer 11. (All tested with small text files on my Windows 7.)

Comment: For anyone ends up here: this is still an issue in 2021. I can confirm it has nothing to do with JS or selected file. Creating an HTML file with nothing but `<input type="file">` and canceling after clicking the button still causes the same issue. Reproducible in IE, Firefox and Chrome. Not reproducible in Edge browser.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome freezes for few seconds when after any use of file field.

It was because I had a shortcut in "Quick Access" menu in windows explorer. This shortcut has been linked with a folder shared by network. I've removed this shortcut and everything is good now.

Comment: Same here, I have a mapped network drive that is not responding, this make a 5 seconds delay. After unmapping the drive, no more delay.
The delay is the same in firefox or chrome, so I wonder if it's not a Windows issue

Comment: Same here, if you want to remove it, on Windows 10, click on the icon Quick access (blue star), then right click on the dead link appearing in the "Frequent folders" panel on the right panel and choose "Unpin/Remove from Quick access". There should be no error message.

Comment: Also encounted this issue and was skeptical it was the network drive, as it was working - however when the network drive was shutdown/powered off temporarily the issue appeared (coincidentally on Windows testing with Edge, Firefox & Chrome). Confirmed that removing the network drive from Quick Access resolves issue! Amazing..

Answer (score 0):

We have to use backticks within the parenthesis where you are using $. Applying single quote can lead to problem as well.