# Html input of type "file" freeze the browser sometimes

Tags: html, file, input

i'm struggling with the classic HTML input of type file. I was using it on my angular application and i had freeze sometimes, the whole browser became unresponsive, and the only thing that works is the scroll.
You can't click any buttons, select any text or even change tab on the browser for about 5 seconds. I tried a lot of different file type and sizes and it doesn't change any of this, it even freeze sometimes when i don't select any file in the explorer and i click the close button directly.

So I thought it was my implementation that was bad and i went to the [Mozilla developper website](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file) where you have an example and I have exactly the same behaviour. I also tried to take only the HTML from the Mozilla website and put it alone on a .html file and again, same behaviour.

This does not occur 100% of the time, but I would argue that on my end it does it about 60/70 % of the times.

I tried it on chrome and Firefox (both up to date), on multiple computer (all running Windows though) and i have the same behaviour on all of them.

I don't have any error or anyting in the consoles.

I don't know what to do with this, i'm pretty sure it can't be the file's input on the whole web that are bugged, but i tried a lot of various things with always the same results. Should i report it somewhere? ( if so, where? ) Or what would you suggest to do to investigate this further?

I couldn't find anyone discussing this issue on the internet apart for [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990111/browser-freezing-after-selecting-file-in-input-field) that had no solution, they also say in this thread that the bug is not reproducible in Edge, but i just tried and it does the same thing.

Thanks for reading me and for any help about this.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome freezes for few seconds when after any use of file field.

It was because I had a shortcut in "Quick Access" menu in windows explorer. This shortcut has been linked with a folder shared by network. I've removed this shortcut and everything is good now.

Same here, I have a mapped network drive that is not responding, this make a 5 seconds delay. After unmapping the drive, no more delay. The delay is the same in firefox or chrome.

Same here, if you want to remove it, on Windows 10, click on the icon Quick access (blue star), then right click on the dead link appearing in the "Frequent folders" panel on the right panel and choose "Unpin/Remove from Quick access". There should be no error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem currently with reactjs, When ever i hit the file upload button, the whole browser freezes.

But to fix this issue, install the following for ubuntu 22.04

`$ sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome`

I hope this helps, you can also go to this link for more references.
[clickhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404550/google-chrome-freeze-uploading-a-file)