# How can I detect that the Cancel Button has been clicked on a <input type="file" /> Select File Dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, file, upload

To handle file uploads on a website we have to use a hidden `<input type="file" />` element.

To find out what file has been selected in the Select File Dialog, we can use the `onchange`event.

But how can we detect if the user has hit the cancel button?
Unfortunately, there is no `oncancel` event.

There exist a lot of workarounds to detect if the user has hit the cancel button, but due to the problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416842/massive-delay-between-closing-of-input-type-file-select-file-dialog-and-onch), none of them worked for me reliably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've invested countless hours looking for a solution. And now I want to share my solution with you.

I use three event handlers:

1. `onchange` event on the file input: To detect when a file has been selected.
2. `onfocus` event on `window`: To detect when the Select File Dialog has been closed.
3. `onmousemove` event on `document.body`: To detect when the interaction is not blocked anymore. Only when this event is called, you can be sure that the `onchange` event of the input element has been called.

The first two points are obvious and you find them in most proposed solutions. But the crucial point is number 3. In other solutions I sometimes faced the problem that I selected a file, but this selected file has not been propagated to the `onchange` event handler before window's got focus.

To make a long story short, here's my implementation:

TypeScript solution:

```typescript
public static selectFile(accept: string = null): Promise<File> {
    return new Promise<File>(async resolve => {
        const fileInputElement = document.createElement('input') as HTMLInputElement;
        fileInputElement.type = 'file';
        fileInputElement.style.opacity = '0';
        if (accept) fileInputElement.accept = accept;
        fileInputElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
            const file = fileInputElement.files[0];
            console.log('File "' + file.name + '" selected.');
            document.body.removeChild(fileInputElement);
            resolve(file);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(fileInputElement);
        setTimeout(_ => {
            fileInputElement.click();
            const onFocus = () => {
                window.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus);
                document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            };
            const onMouseMove = () => {
                document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                if (!fileInputElement.files.length) {
                    document.body.removeChild(fileInputElement);
                    console.log('No file selected.');
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

JavaScript solution:

```js
function selectFile(accept = null) {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        const fileInputElement = document.createElement('input');
        fileInputElement.type = 'file';
        fileInputElement.style.opacity = '0';
        if (accept) fileInputElement.accept = accept;
        fileInputElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
            const file = fileInputElement.files[0];
            console.log('File "' + file.name + '" selected.');
            document.body.removeChild(fileInputElement);
            resolve(file);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(fileInputElement);
        setTimeout(_ => {
            fileInputElement.click();
            const onFocus = () => {
                window.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus);
                document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            };
            const onMouseMove = () => {
                document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                if (!fileInputElement.files.length) {
                    document.body.removeChild(fileInputElement);
                    console.log('No file selected.');
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: It works but I found an edge case (found on Chrome): when double-clicking on a file in the dialog to select it, the input `change` event seems to not have enough time to propagate and the console prints "No file selected."