# How to pause promise chain to wait for a button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, promise, vuejs3

I'm trying to chain some backend calls to process a file, but the entire workflow needs some input from the user midway. I'm not sure how to pause the execution until the user clicks a button to "`Continue`" after working with a modal.

So the process is as follows:

1. User selects a file which triggers an event to upload some data.
2. I get the response from the previous call, open up a modal with a form. I need to pause here.
3. Fill the form, click "`Continue`" button to resume promise chain.
4. Trigger another call to submit more info to another endpoint.

So each of these steps relate to an HTTP request, using `axios`, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to chain the promises.

Right now I have something like:

```js
onFileSelected(event) {
  // code here
  axios
    .post("")
    .then((res) => {
      // Here I need to open the modal, and wait for the button click
    })
    .then(() => {
      anotherMethod();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Vue? If you are, please state that in the question body in addition to tagging.

Comment: `Here I need to open the modal, and wait for the button click` make a promise that resolves once the button is clicked - importantly, return that promise inside `.then` - without knowing your modal code, it's a bit difficult to help though

Comment: Have a look at [How can I use async / await in my function to wait for an event to fire on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264023/1048572)

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, the modal code is just another axios call that should be triggered on the click of the same `Continue` button, I didn't think it was too relevant

Comment: Just Call anotherMethod(); in Modal on button-"Yes" click + closeModal().

Answer (score 1):

Promises themselves don't provide a way to pause their execution, but you can achieve this using the async/await syntax. Create a custom promise that resolves when the user clicks the "Continue" button. Something like this,

```js
async function onFileSelected(event) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("") // Upload data
    await showModalAndWaitForUserInteraction() // Pause and wait for user input

    await anotherMethod() // Continue after user interaction

    // Continue with the rest of your promise chain
    const anotherResponse = await axios.post("") // Submit more info to another endpoint
    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here
  }
}

function showModalAndWaitForUserInteraction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Show the modal with button
    // ...modal logic
    // then resolve() 
  })
}
```

Comment: You don't _need_ async/await; you could use this approach with a `.then()` chain as well.